# JavaScript Event when Select Options are shown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

What event, if any, is triggered when a `<select>` element shows/hides its list of `<options>`?

Example:

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

When you click with a mouse into this select box the browser shows the list of options.

However when you tab into the select box the browser does not show the list of options.

Is the only way to check for a mouseup event within the select element or am I missing something obvious?

```
$(document.body).on('mouseup', 'select', function(){            
    console.log('Either shown or hidden the options...but which?')
});
```

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm trying to add a class to the `<select>` element when its showing the `<options>` so that I can shown a different custom caret style when the browser is displaying the "options popover" than when it's not.

Comment: use the `on change` of `jquery`

Comment: what about on click cor adding the class and onchange for removing it?

Comment: A mouse event handler isn't enough because using the keyboard it is possible to tab into a select element and then press alt-down or alt-up to drop and retract the list. (Regarding what you're actually trying to achieve, why would you do that? Users expect standard behaviour from standard controls like select elements.)

Answer (score 0):

That would mean that the select element is in focus. So in this scenario you wouldn't need javascript. You can cater for this using css.

```
select:focus {
  color:red;
}
```

But if you did want to use jquery it would look something like this:

```
$("select").focus(function(){
  console.log(" h1 ");
})
```

Using purely javascript, give your select an id="select" and you could do something like this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("select");
x.addEventListener("focus", myFocusFunction, true);
x.addEventListener("blur", myBlurFunction, true);

function myFocusFunction() {
    document.getElementById("select").style.backgroundColor = "yellow"; 
}

function myBlurFunction() {
    document.getElementById("select").style.backgroundColor = ""; 
}
```

Comment: The question asked if there was an event for when the list drops down (or hides again), which is not the same thing as the select element receiving focus.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes you are correct. It's not a correct answer to the question. There is no javascript event associated with the select element displaying it's options.

Comment: @user300838 if you really want to be able to achieve the desired effect of adding a class to the select element when it is open you'll probably need to use a jquery plugin like http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/index.html, https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ or https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/